# SharePoint crawl too slow

Tags: sharepoint-server, search, enterprise-search

I have a SharePoint farm with:

3 Front end servers (load balanced)

1 app server

2 Index servers

2 Sql servers (cluseter 1 active 1 passive)

**Index servers**

24 GB memory, 6 cores, 2ghz, D drive has 1 TB disk (search index is stored here)

As of today there is ca. 12 million items beeing crawled and it takes 9.5 items per second

[image: SEARCH]
[image: reduced]

Full crawl was set up on the farm but it took 8+ days to finish. So we did the next best thing and set it to incrimental.

There are also 96 craw rules. the vast majority of theese are Exclusion rules but there are also 10 inclusion rules.

**If we want to set it to Full Crawl what do i do to make it finish in a few hours instead of few days?**

Answer (score 1):

This one is easy troubleshooting, you have to investigate from every angle. I.e.

1. Antivirus, make sure exclusion for SharePoint folders in place. AV should not crawl index location and SharePoint related folders.
2. Also examine if there is resource fighting while crawl is running...sometime AV consume too much.
3. If you have any other auditing tool install on server than make sure that app not slowing down it.
4. Check the server resources...i.e cpu,memory and disk.
5. You have to check crawl logs for a clue.
6. Check if there is a site collection which have a lot of items in, any customization.
7. You have to check crawl rule may be they are too many.

Follow this blog for more tips for troubleshooting.https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kristopherloranger/2013/05/30/sharepoint-2013-crawler-troubleshooting-concepts/

https://collab365.community/forum/topics/sharepoint-2010-slow-full-crawl/?ap_paged=2

Comment: there is no AV on the farm. there are no other auditing tools on the farm. we do however have 96 crawl rules as i stated above in my original post. and there is considerable customisation on the 4000 site collections we currently have

Answer (score 1):

You might try buying as large of an SSD as you can afford and put the search index on that.  Even better if that's the only thing the SSD will host.